# How to stop all units belonging to the same target?

Tags: systemd

I'm wondering how to stop all units that are grouped together by the same target.

My setup is as follows. I have several unit config files that read:

```
[Unit]
...

[Service]
...

[Install]
WantedBy=mycustom.target
```

When I run

```
# systemctl start mycustom.target
```

Those units that "are wanted by" `mycustom.target` start correctly. Now, I would also like to be able stop all units that are wanted by `mycustom.target`. I tried:

```
# systemctl stop mycustom.target
```

This doesn't do anything though. Is there a way to make this work without having to stop all units that are (explicitly) wanted by the same target?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the `PartOf=` directive.

> Configures dependencies similar to Requires=, but limited to stopping and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts the units listed here, the action is propagated to this unit. Note that this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the listed units.

`PartOf=mycustom.target`

Comment: Should I combine it with `StopWhenUnneeded` or is it implied?

Comment: It seems that `StopWhenUnneeded` is not necessary when using `PartOf`. @PSSGCSim

Comment: Can confirm that ```StopWhenUnneeded``` can be ignored.

Answer (score 10):

### Edit: the `PartOf=` directive, which did not exist at the time of writing this answer, is a better solution. See another answer for details.

There are two ways: an implicit and an explicit.

### First way — `StopWhenUnneeded=`

The first way is to use the [`StopWhenUnneeded=`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StopWhenUnneeded=) directive. If a unit has `StopWhenUnneeded=yes`, it will be automatically stopped when there becomes no active unit which `Wants=`/`Requires=` the unit in question. Hence:

- this will only work if these units are `WantedBy=` *only* by `mycustom.target`;
- you will be unable to start any of these units manually (i. e. `systemctl start myunit.service` will start it and immediately stop it afterwards).

### Second way — a shell pipeline

The second way is to construct a simple shell pipeline, using `systemctl show -p` to extract the dependency list of `mycustom.target`.

More specifically, `systemctl show UNIT` will show *all* properties of a unit in a KEY=VALUE form, and `systemctl show -p PROPERTIES UNIT` will do the same, limiting the set of shown properties. So:

```
systemctl stop -- $(systemctl show -p Wants mycustom.target | cut -d= -f2)
```