# Have SystemD spawn N processes?

Tags: systemd, supervisord

At my organization, we have a number of queue consuming worker processes. We're currently using SupervisorD to manage them, but would like to use SystemD if possible for certain advantages therein. I'm fairly experienced with writing custom units, but I don't immediately have an analog in SystemD land for this.

In the [SupervisorD documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings) a parameter called `numprocs` is detailed which allows one to set the number of processes they'd like to be started with the service. If I want 30 processes started, it's a one-line change.

Is there a setting in SystemD units that will allow me to specify how many of these processes I'd like started?

Comment: Are you trying to create multiple instances of the same unit? If so, you might want to look at http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html

Answer (score 36):

What Munir mentioned is exactly how you do this. Basically you create a `service` file, and start it 30 times. Now that may seem a little unweildy, but it has advantages, such as being able to shut one of them down if it's misbehaving, and not have to shut all of them down. There are also some things you can do to make management easier.

First, the unit file. Create a file, such as `/etc/systemd/system/test@.service`. The important bit is the `@` symbol.

It's contents might look like:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 600 %I

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then start it with `systemctl start test@1.service`, `systemctl start test@2.service`.
The processes that get launched will look like:

```
root     17222  19   0  0.0  0.0 Ss         00:05 /bin/sleep 600 1
root     17233  19   0  0.0  0.0 Ss         00:02 /bin/sleep 600 2
```

Notice that the `%I` got substituted with whatever you put after the `@` when you started it.

You can start all 30 with a little shell-fu:

```
systemctl start test@{1..30}.service
```

You can also enable them at boot like any normal service: `systemctl enable test@1.service`.

Now, what I meant by things you can do to make management easier: Maybe you don't want to have to use `test@{1..30}.service` for managing them all. It is a little unwieldy. You can instead create a new target for your service.

Create `/etc/systemd/system/test.target` with:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then adjust the `/etc/systemd/system/test@.service` so that it looks like:

```
[Unit]
StopWhenUnneeded=true

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sleep 600 %I

[Install]
WantedBy=test.target
```

Reload systemd with `systemctl daemon-reload` (only necessary if you are modifying the unit file, and didn't skip the earlier version of it). And now enable all the services you want to be managed by doing `systemctl enable test@{1..30}.service`.
*(If you had previously enabled the service while it had `WantedBy=multi-user.target`, disable it first to clear out the dependency)*

You can now do `systemctl start test.target` and `systemctl stop test.target`, and it will start/stop all 30 processes.
And again, you can enable at boot like any other unit file: `systemctl enable test.target`.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, I searched this for several days.

Comment: Do you know if that will restart processes that fail?

Comment: @bastian: you can use `Restart=on-failure`. Read the `systemd.service` man page for more.

Comment: Very helpful but replacing "StopWhenUnneeded=true" by PartOf=test.target is a better solution today in 2021. See [how to stop units of the same target](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212438/how-to-stop-all-units-belonging-to-the-same-target) as it solves issues with restarting the service for instance.

Comment: @phemmer, you're a `systemd` guru!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my example using a python script that runs in a virtualenv:

`/etc/systemd/system/my-worker@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=manages my worker service, instance %i
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Type=idle
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/virtualenvs/bin/python /path/to/my/script.py
Restart=always
TimeoutStartSec=10
RestartSec=10
```

Disable: `sudo systemctl disable my-worker\@{1..30}.service`

Enable N workers: `sudo systemctl enable my-worker\@{1..2}.service`

Reload: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Start: `sudo systemctl start my-worker@2.service`

Check status: `sudo systemctl status my-worker@1`