# Starting 'n' copies of a daemon with systemd

Tags: systemd, rabbitmq

I would like to have systemd start up a number of processing servers for a RabbitMQ RPC queue. I tried to follow the example in [Have SystemD spawn N processes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288236/have-systemd-spawn-n-processes) to have a single `systemctl` command to start/stop the servers.

Here are my unit file and template file.

`ansiblepbserver@.service:`

```
[Unit]
Description=RabbitMQ rpc queue server instance %i for ansiblePB_rpc_queue
Requires=rabbitmq-server.servic
After=multi-user.target rabbitmq-server.service
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
PermissionsStartOnly=true
Type=idle
User=secretuser
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /app/bin/ansibleplaybookserver.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=ansiblePB.servers.service
```

`ansiblePB.servers.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Controlling service for the multiple ansiblePB servers

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Workflow:

1. Enable servers:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable ansibleserver@{1..2}.service
   ```
2. Start everything for the first time

   ```
   sudo systemctl start ansiblePB.servers.service
   ```

It fails with:

```
Failed to start ansiblePB.servers.service: Unit is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status ansiblePB.servers.service' for details.
```

Status gives me:

```
ansiblePB.servers.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

The docs say have to have at least `ExecStart` or `ExecStop`, but the example in the weblink above does not include either and I don't know what I would set them to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which of the two answers at that Q&A are you asserting says to do what you have done?

Comment: Where did you get the idea for `ansiblePB.servers.service`? What is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: As in the question you linked, your `ansiblePB.servers.service` perhaps should not be a `.service` but a `.target` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a [`.target`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html) file for ansiblePB, not a service.

This is what the question you linked to uses.