# stop all units in a custom target without modify the units

Tags: systemd

I am aware if I use [`PartOf=` in the units](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212438/how-to-stop-all-units-belonging-to-the-same-target), then all units can be stopped when the target stopped. However, I am not in control of those units file, so every time I upgrade the software, the unit files get changed back to previous state. I can of course rename them and maintain them myself, but it is annoying. I wonder if there is any  I can just list those services in my custom target file. Then after I do `systemctl stop mycustom.target`, all units can be stopped.

```
[Unit]
Requires=a.service b.service ...
SomeMagic=a.service b.service ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to override unit files by making a unit file in `/etc/systemd/system/`.
Actually the unit files in `/usr/lib/systemd/` are supplied by vendor and will be downloaded from repository while updating the package.

please have a look at `man systemd.unit` section `Example 2. Overriding vendor settings`